# hibernate, to be lazy or not to be lazy?

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, lazy-evaluation

I have `entity A`, which has a many-to-many relation to `entity B`.

So the table layout is :     `A, AB(mapping table), B`

To get an object of entity A: 
I call `A.getById()` which does `getHibernateTemplate().get(A.class, id)`   using spring and hibernate.

The problem is, sometimes ensuing code will just need A, sometimes  ensuing code will continue to access the associated B's, so we'd like to use **lazy loading** in some cases and **eager** in some other cases. but the problem is that all database access is provided through the same single `ADao.java`, so there is only one method `getById()`.

**Should I create two versions of method getById()?**

But then for more complex cases, if A is also attached to C through many-to-many, then there could be variants of lazy-loading-C and eager-loading-C,so the required `getById()` variants quickly grows exponentially.

what is your opinion on this choice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general considerations take a look at the Hibernate 3.6 docs about [fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching). The default fetching strategy is defined in mapping annotations or in a hbm.xml file. There are three ways to dynamically switch from a default lazy-loading strategy to an eager-loading strategy. The first two require separate implementations of DAO methods for lazy-loading and eager-loading use cases:

1. `Criteria.setFetchMode()` in a Hibernate Criteria query
2. `FETCH` keyword in a HQL query
3. Since Hibernate 3.5 (not quite sure now, maybe 3.6) there is the third option of using [fetch profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles) to dynamically switch from lazy-loading to eager-loading.

A fetch profile is enabled/disabled on a session scope. So, provided the desired fetch profile is set in the current session, you can use the same DAO method for a lazy-loading as well as for an eager-loading use case.

The important thing to be aware of here is that you **can only switch from a lazy-loading strategy** defined in annotations or in a hbm.xml file **to an eager-loading strategy** and not vice versa. This restriction is independent of the method used for switching the fetching strategy.

Comment: FetchProfile is great. Is there an equivalent for update?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you described the problem correctly. It's just a tradeoff between simplicity (just one method) and performance (two methods, each returning exactly what is needed). If the response time is correct by just using the single method and lazy-loading the Bs, then don't touch anything. If the response time is too long, and you have measured that eager-loading it would make it correct, then introduce a new method.

Keep things simple, and optimize only if needed. Lazy-loading associations is fast, because it just make a query on a foreign key, whcih should be indexed in the database.

Also not that loading two toMany associations is pretty rare: it's common to show all the products of a category on a page, but it's uncommon to show all the puchases of all the products of a category.